# Disabling Authorization endpoint in Spring Oauth

Tags: spring-oauth2

I am spring boot oauth2 2.0.0.RELEASE.

I am trying to disable the authorize endpoints as we wont be using it ?
Is there a configuration I can set to disable it ? We only use the token endpoint

Comment: Have you found a way to do that ?